# Can I use relative reference indexes without quotation marks in Google Sheets as arguments in custom App Script functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to write a function in Google Sheets using Google App Script. For example, the following code takes the argument cellReference, and returns the value of that referenced cell.

```
function myFunction(cellReference) {
toReturn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellReference);
return (cellReference);
}
```

However, this function requires to parse in the argument as a string, which prevents me from using the features of the argument as a relative cell reference in Google Sheets.

For example, I cannot write myFunction(A1), but I have to write myFunction("A1"). Normally I would just copy the cell, and the cell reference will change dynamically, but this feature is prevented by writing in quotation marks.

Is there a way to get around this issue?

I tried using the CONCAT() function in google sheets, but it doesn't allow to write """, so I can't really add quotation marks to the ends of the argument this way.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, in your situation is this post useful? [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/12/23/automatic-recalculation-of-custom-function-on-spreadsheet-part-1/) When this post is used, when `=myFunction("A1",A1)` is used, 1st argument is used as `cellReference` of `myFunction(cellReference)`. And, 2nd argument is used for recalculating when cell "A1" is edited. I posted it as a comment because I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`CELL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071) or `ADDRESS+ROW+COLUMN`:

```
=MYFUNCTION(CELL("address",A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your function does not return the value in the cell.  If you wish to return the value in the cell you will require something like this:

```
function myFunction(cellReference) {
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellReference).getValue();
  return (r);
}
```